# How to draw a link from the source?

Tags: vbscript, getelementsbyclassname

source:

```
<div class="filmPosterBox">
    <div id="filmPosterLink" class="hide"/>
    <div class="posterLightbox">
        <a class="film_mini" href="http://1.fwcsd.pl/df/2eee.jpg" rel="v:image">
            <img title="tytulek(2011)" alt="tytul film" src="http://1.cos.pl/coes/cod2scdos.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

wants to draw the same link: (*broken link*)

I created something but does not work as it should:

```
sPosterFile = oInternetExplorer.Document.getElementsByClassName("posterLightbox")(0) _
             .getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerHTML
```

Comment: I removed the link to your image http://1.fwcsd.pl/df/2eee.jpg which was broken. Please add the correct link if necessary by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target of a link is stored in the tag's `href` attribute, not in the inner HTML.

```
sPosterFile = oInternetExplorer.Document _
                .getElementsByClassName("posterLightbox")(0) _
                .getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
```